# Bash script - remove few item from array

Tags: xml, bash, shell, unix

I have created shell script to read a file and store elements into array.

Now i want to remove some elements from array which has `</` in it.

my xml file:

```
<Execution_Stats>
<Total_Executions>1</Total_Executions>  
<Total_Errors>0</Total_Errors>
<SQL_Analysis>
    <NOT_COMPARED>1</NOT_COMPARED>
    <MATCHED>0</MATCHED>
    <NOT_MATCHED>0</NOT_MATCHED>
    <ERROR>0</ERROR>
</SQL_Analysis>
<Data_Analysis>
    <NOT_COMPARED>0</NOT_COMPARED>
    <MATCHED>0</MATCHED>
    <NOT_MATCHED>1</NOT_MATCHED>
    <ERROR>0</ERROR>
</Data_Analysis>
<Graph_Analysis>
    <NOT_COMPARED>1</NOT_COMPARED>
    <MATCHED>0</MATCHED>
    <NOT_MATCHED>0</NOT_MATCHED>
    <ERROR>0</ERROR>
</Graph_Analysis>
<Excel_Analysis>
    <NOT_COMPARED>1</NOT_COMPARED>
    <MATCHED>0</MATCHED>
    <NOT_MATCHED>0</NOT_MATCHED>
    <ERROR>0</ERROR>
</Excel_Analysis>
<Pdf_Analysis>
    <NOT_COMPARED>1</NOT_COMPARED>
    <MATCHED>0</MATCHED>
    <NOT_MATCHED>0</NOT_MATCHED>
    <ERROR>0</ERROR>
</Pdf_Analysis>
</Execution_Stats>
```

shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 txt=($(grep  '_Analysis' "results.xml"))

 unset(txt[1])
 unset(txt[3])
 unset(txt[5])
 unset(txt[7])
 unset(txt[9])
```

but i am not getting result as i expected.

I would like to see output like

```
txt[0]=SQL_Analysis
txt[1]=Data_Analysis
txt[2]=Graph_Analysis
txt[3]=Excel_Analysis
txt[4]=PDF_Analysis
```

but getting

```
txt[0]=SQL_Analysis
txt[1]=
txt[2]=Data_Analysis
txt[3]=
txt[4]=Graph_Analysis
txt[5]=
txt[6]=Excel_Analysis
txt[7]=
txt[8]=PDF_Analysis
txt[9]=
```

Or if there is a way where i cannot select any text which start with `</` from the file?

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse XML.

Comment: You could try `grep  '<[A-Z].*_Analysis' results.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong to unset a variable. I'm not even sure how your code is executing as what you have results in a syntax error for me.
Your code:

```
#!/bin/bash

txt=($(grep  '_Analysis' "test.xml"))

unset(txt[1])
unset(txt[3])
unset(txt[5])
unset(txt[7])
unset(txt[9])
```

Output:

```
test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `txt[1]'
test.sh: line 5: `unset(txt[1])'
```

See below:

```
#!/bin/bash

txt=($(grep  '_Analysis' "test.xml"))

unset 'txt[1]'
unset 'txt[3]'
unset 'txt[5]'
unset 'txt[7]'
unset 'txt[9]'

for key in ${txt[@]}; do
    echo $key
done
```

Which gives me:

```
dumbledore@ansible1a [OPS]:~ > bash test.sh
<SQL_Analysis>
<Data_Analysis>
<Graph_Analysis>
<Excel_Analysis>
<Pdf_Analysis>
```